# How to Select data trough 2 tables with ONE Query

Tags: mysql

Every `client` has their own `project` but not all of them has `project`.

I want to  **select** all `clients` that **has** project but I do not know how to do it!

I get **all** clients with this query:

```
SELECT `clients` FROM `reps` WHERE `clients` != ''
```

My goal is to get data which has **only** `project`

These are my database tables:

**Table Clients:** (Table name = `reps`)

```
1   id      varchar(12)        // example: stckvrflw
2   ctitle  varchar(100)       // example: StackOverflow
```

**Table Projects:** (Table name = `verkocht`)

```
1   id      varchar(11)         // example: 1
2   title   varchar(100)        // example: This is an Example
```

Do you have a solution on my problem?

Comment: The PHP tag seems to be irrelevant, seems to just be a query/mysql question. Is there an issue with the PHP implementation? (You are open to SQL injections, should parameterize)

Comment: provide all three table structure so getting idea about your requirement and right query about it.

Comment: I'd also recommend always using aliases with some relation to the table's name (as both answers here have). With incremented aliases you will always need to find the `join` statement to see which table is which.

Answer (score 0):

You have the `client` in the `milestones` table, so doesn't this do what you want?

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.client
FROM `milestones` m;
```

Comment: Where do I write this?

Comment: @Haffoo . . . "But how can I select all clients that has milestones?"  This query would appear to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to join the `projects` and the `milestones` tables. Since you gave no information on your database shema, the field names have to be adjusted. You also have to check for deleted or hidden flags if you have some:

```
SELECT c.* FROM clients c
INNER JOIN projects p ON p.client = c.id
INNER JOIN milestones m ON m.project = p.id
GROUP BY c.id
```

Comment: This did not worked sir. I still have in my array of query projects with no milestones. I only Need projects that **has** milestones

Comment: if you want some help, then post your database structure

Comment: the DATABASE STRUCTURE, it's the third time I'm writing it

Comment: I re-wrote my question

Comment: @Haffoo If this doesn't works that means that you have projects linked in your milestones table that don't have milestones which doesn't make sense.

Comment: yes that is the point of my question! i dont want to show project that does not have milestones because it does not make sense

Comment: @Haffoo Bottom line question is, how can you identify which project has a milestone? Once you answer that we can help you with your query.

Comment: by cookie as i said in my question. If a user pressed on client X, then the value of `cookie  'client'` will be `'x'`. After a user has chosed a `client`, then the selector of 'projects' will appear becasue `cookie 'client'` has a value in this case `'X'`. the query of `project` is based on the `cookie 'client'`. This is all explained in my question sir! Thanks